# Regex: how to find out if string contains anything except specified set

Tags: php

I need to know if string contains anything but figures, spaces, "+/*/-" signs and dots. I.e. strings like:

- 123 - 456
- 123.45
- 12345
- 12345 - 12.34

should not match. Only string like

- 123 - abcdef
- abcdef 123
- 123 abcdef 12.34

should match my expression.

So, I need to create an expression that matches everything except \d, \s, -, ., (any other single char I specify).

I'm using regex101 to test my expressions and I found out that not all expressions from this resource work in PHP. This makes things tougher...

Update: I need expression that matches strings in any langauge, so only excluding will work, I believe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below regex -

```
^[0-9- *.+]*$
```

Also, check it pass all you tests - https://regex101.com/r/K59IUZ/1